# How run function when another ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function:

```
function functionName($results) {
    //some stuff
    disableSave()
}
```

When this function is executed I want to run the function `enableSave()`

How can I do it?

I try to pass this function as a callback but I can't understand where I should write what this function will do

```
function functionName($results, callback) {
    disableSave()
    callback()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function enableSave() {
   //some code here
   console.log('enableSave')
}

function disableSave() {
   //some code here
   console.log('disableSave')
}

function functionName(results, callback) {
  console.log('functionName')
  disableSave()
  callback()
}

functionName('', enableSave)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: You are absolutely right, usually I attach the code and immediately edit it with the explanations, but I had a mess at work so I will have to postpone the editing for a little while